Is there any code used by Instagram for shared Instagram reel into DMs?
So I'm trying to create an auto-reply on Instagram DM whenever a user shared a reel into my DM, the bot will automatically send info about the specific reels (in this case I used third party app/web such as Manychat or Chatfuel). They have the tools to automatically reply a DM with certain keyword, but in this case the keyword is shared reel.
I have tried to set the keyword with my Instagram post ID, but it doesn't work. I wonder if someone know, is there any sort of code behind a shared reel that can be used as keyword trigger?
